# GNU date command jumbling day and year when giving the proper format specifier

Tags: date

I have come across this weird behaviour of GNU date.

```
date -d "29-May-20 09:29 1 minute" +"%d-%b-%y %H:%M"
```

gives output: *29-May-20 09:30* --> Note: I have given here the abbreviated month name format specifier '%b'

But,

```
date -d "29-05-20 09:29 1 minute" +"%d-%m-%y %H:%M"
```

gives output: *20-05-29 09:30* --> I mean the year and the date field is jumbled, though I have given the correct format specifier '%m' for the month field. How to make it work to give the expected output *29-05-20*?

Comment: Read carefully about how GNU date parses user input: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html => "For numeric months, the ISO 8601 format ‘year-month-day’ is allowed, where year is any positive number, month is a number between 01 and 12, and day is a number between 01 and 31. "

Answer (score 0):

The `+FORMAT` describes the output, not how the argument to `-d` is parsed. If you want to ensure that is parsed the way you want, you should feed it an unambiguous representation

Comment: `Fox` then it should be `dd-mm-yy` right? according to the format specifier `"%d-%m-%y"` but I am getting the `yy-mm-dd` as output

Comment: not at all. let me rephrase: the format specifier has absolutely nothing to do with that argument. The fully-numeric date you've given is assumed to by yy-mm-dd (if possible), and is then output according to the format specifier, which has the dd part and the yy part in the opposite order